# Keep Weather info even when offline

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm creating a widget for the iPhone lockscreen using CSS/HTML. I can't figure out how to keep the weather info from disappearing when the phone screen turns off after a minute or when the phone is offline. Any tips? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var iconExtWall = '.png'
var iconExtLock = '.png'
var locale = 'Beirut, Lebanon'
var iconSetWall = 'stardock'
var iconSetLock = 'stardock'
var enableWallpaper = true
var isCelsius = true
var useRealFeel = false
var enableLockScreen = true
var source = 'appleAccuweatherStolen'
var stylesheetWall = 'mini'
var stylesheetLock = 'Under_StatusBar'
var updateInterval = 15


var postal;
var demoMode = false;
var enabled;

if (location.href.indexOf("Wallpaper")  > 0){
    stylesheet = stylesheetLock;
    iconSet = iconSetLock;
    iconExt = iconExtLock;
    enabled = enableLockScreen;
}else{
    stylesheet = stylesheetWall;
    iconSet = iconSetWall;
    iconExt = iconExtWall;
    enabled = enableWallpaper;
}

if(enabled == true){
if(iconSet == null || iconSet == 'null' || iconSet == ""){
    var iconSet = stylesheet;
}

var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var styleNode = document.createElement('link');
styleNode.type = 'text/css';
styleNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
styleNode.href = 'Stylesheets/'+stylesheet+'.css';
headID.appendChild(styleNode);

var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptNode.src = 'Sources/'+source+'.js';
headID.appendChild(scriptNode);
}

function onLoad(){
    if (enabled == true){ 
    if (demoMode == true){
        document.getElementById("weatherIcon").src="IconSets/"+iconSet+"/"+"cloudy1"+iconExt;
        document.getElementById("city").innerText="Somewhere";
        document.getElementById("desc").innerText="Partly Cloudy";
        document.getElementById("temp").innerText="100�";       
        document.getElementById("forecast").innerText="Sun";    
    }else{ 
    document.getElementById("weatherIcon").src="IconSets/"+iconSet+"/"+"dunno"+iconExt;
    validateWeatherLocation(escape(locale).replace(/^%u/g, "%"), setPostal)
    }
    }else{
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText='';
    }
}

function convertTemp(num)
{
    if (isCelsius == true)
        return Math.round ((num - 32) * 5 / 9);
    else
        return num;
}

function setPostal(obj){

    if (obj.error == false){
        if(obj.cities.length > 0){
            postal = escape(obj.cities[0].zip).replace(/^%u/g, "%")
            document.getElementById("WeatherContainer").className = ""; 
            weatherRefresherTemp();
        }else{
            document.getElementById("city").innerText="Not Found";
            document.getElementById("WeatherContainer").className = "errorLocaleNotFound";  
        }
    }else{
        document.getElementById("city").innerText=obj.errorString;
        document.getElementById("WeatherContainer").className = "errorLocaleValidate";  
        setTimeout('validateWeatherLocation(escape(locale).replace(/^%u/g, "%"), setPostal)', Math.round(1000*60*5));
    }
}

function dealWithWeather(obj){
       var translatedesc="description";
    if (obj.error == false){
        document.getElementById("city").innerText=obj.city;
        document.getElementById("city2").innerText=obj.city;

        document.getElementById("desc").innerText=obj.description.toLowerCase();


        if(useRealFeel == true){
            tempValue = convertTemp(obj.realFeel);
        }else{
            tempValue = convertTemp(obj.temp)
        }
        document.getElementById("temp").innerText=tempValue+"º";
        document.getElementById("weatherIcon").src="IconSets/"+iconSet+"/"+MiniIcons[obj.icon]+iconExt;

        /*ProductRed*/
        lastResults = new Array;
        lastResults[0] = {daycode:obj.daycode, icon:obj.icon, hi:obj.hi, lo:obj.lo, now:obj.temp};
        var c = obj.forecast.length;
        var titi = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
        var toto =new Date();
        var tutu = toto.getDay();
        var tata;
        if (c > 6) c = 6; // just to be safe
        for (var i=0; i<c; ++i)
        {
        var forecast = obj.forecast[i];

        tata = tutu + i;
        if(tata > 6) {tata = tata - 7;}
        document.getElementById('day'+i).innerText = titi[tata];
        document.getElementById('hi'+i).innerHTML = convertTemp(forecast.hi)+'&#176 ';
        document.getElementById('low'+i).innerHTML= convertTemp(forecast.lo)+'&#176 ';
        document.getElementById('wIcon'+i).src="IconSets/"+iconSet+"/"+MiniIcons[forecast.icon]+iconExt;

        lastResults[i+1] = {daycode:forecast.daycode, icon:forecast.icon, hi:forecast.hi, lo:forecast.lo};
        }
        /*ProductRed*/

        document.getElementById("WeatherContainer").className = ""; 



    }else{
        //Could be down to any number of things, which is unhelpful...
        document.getElementById("WeatherContainer").className = "errorWeatherDataFetch";    
    }

var this_date_timestamp = new Date()
var this_weekday = this_date_timestamp.getDay()
var this_date = this_date_timestamp.getDate()
var this_month = this_date_timestamp.getMonth()
var this_year = this_date_timestamp.getYear()

if (this_year < 1000)
    this_year+= 1900;
if (this_year==101)
    this_year=2001;

}

function weatherRefresherTemp(){ //I'm a bastard ugly hack. Hate me.
    fetchWeatherData(dealWithWeather,postal);
    setTimeout(weatherRefresherTemp, 60*1000*updateInterval);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing a closing curly bracket at the end of your code

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Thanks, fixed it. Any ideas on how I could 'cache' the weather, and have it reload when connected to internet?

Comment: You could use [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: I just found something called [Offline.js,](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) 'Every app goes offline' Hope it helps :) Looking for other options...

Comment: I found another option, though it's a bit complex.  You could [store to the user's localhost DB](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-synchronized-online-offline-data-application-with-javascript-and-jaydata)

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Thanks man! I'll check them all out